# Does projective transformation preserve convexity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, projective-geometry

Does projective transformation preserve convexity?

Notice: Ignore the trivial case which projects a convex curve to a straight line.

Comment: Do you mean: Suppose that $C\subset A^n \subset RP^n$ is a convex subset of the affine space $A^n$ and suppose that $g\in PGL(n+1,R)$ sends $C$ to another subset of $A^n$. Is $g(C)$ convex in $A^n$?

Comment: Does convex mean that every real projective line in the real projective space intersects the set in a path connected subset with path connected complement? I can't think of how else to define it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP wanted, but I recently wanted the following lemma: Let $g: \mathbb{RP}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ be a projective linear automorphism. We think of $g$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus H$ to $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus H'$ for hyperplanes $H$ and $H'$, so $H$ is the hyperplane which is "sent to infinity" and $H'$ is the hyperplane which is "the image of the plane at infinity". Let $K$ be a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$, disjoint from $H$. Then $g(K)$ is also convex.

Comment: More colloquially: Look at a drawing of a checkerboard in two point perspective. The squares of the checkerboard are convex in real life, and they are also drawn convex on the page.

Answer (score 1):

When you say projective transformation in the context of convex sets, I think of the following:

> If $C\subset\Bbb R^d$ is convex, then consider the cone $\mathrm{cone}(C\times \{1\})\subset\Bbb R^{d+1}$. The projective transformations of $C$ are the intersections of hyperplanes $\pi\subset\Bbb R^{d+1}$ with this cone.

If this is what you mean, then these transformations are apparently convex, because the cone is convex, so is $\pi$, and so must be their intersection.

In a different context one can state that hyperbolas are projective transformations of ellipses, the latter is convex but the former is not (speaking about the "interior"). So it is not true in this case.